# Error when running python server with Flask: ImportError: No module named bcrypt

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt

I am new to python and Flask and want to run a project that a friend of mine wrote.

When I run `$ python server.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bcrypt
ImportError: No module named bcrypt
```

I also ran the following commands in the root of the directory but the issue remains:

```
pip install Flask
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install bcrpyt
```

The `requirements.txt` looks as follows:

```
aniso8601==1.0.0
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-PyMongo==0.3.1
Flask-RESTful==0.3.4
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
pymongo==3.0.3
pytz==2015.4
six==1.9.0
Werkzeug==0.10.4
wheel==0.24.0
```

The first lines of `server.py` look as follows (before the actual implementation begins):

```
import bcrypt
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from pymongo import MongoClient
from utils.mongo_json_encoder import JSONEncoder
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)
mongo = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
app.db = mongo.develop_database
app.bcrypt_rounds = 12
api = Api(app)
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: add it to your `requirements` file and run `pip install -r requirements.txt` again.If you are using a virtualenv, make sure you have that activated

Comment: Try  **from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a rather stupid error, the problem was that I used `python` and `pip` rather than `python3` and `pip3`.

Answer (score -2):

For flask you should use `flask-bcrypt`, to install write this

```
pip install flask-bcrypt
```

In code instead of  `import bcrypt` You should write

```
from flask.ext.bcrypt import *
```